# Has the ${JAVA_DIR} JPS manifest property disappeared in the tomcat8?

Tags: jelastic

I am trying to upgrade my Jelastic JPS application manifest file to add tomcat8 instead of tomcat7 to my container. However the upload section below now fails with a message:

> File name [${JAVA_LIB}] is in wrong format. File name length must be
>   less than 255 characters.

```
"upload": [
                {
                    "nodeType": "tomcat8",
                    "sourcePath": "http://widgets.jelastichosting.nl/magnolia/mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar",
                    "destPath": "${JAVA_LIB}/mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar"
                }
            ],
```

It seems that the ${JAVA_LIB} property is no longer supported?

If so, is this document anywhere Jelastic people? And also: how do I now upload a JAR to Tomcat's lib folder? I tried ${WEBAPPS}/../lib/ but this also fails..

cheers

Edgar

Comment: Oh, and the ${SERVER_CONF} variable also no longer seems to work.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please check Jelastic Docs by the following link http://docs.jelastic.com/packaging-standard-placeholders and you will not find any information about file path placeholders for the Tomcat8 node type.

As a solution please use full path for uploading JAR to Tomcat's lib folder.

Comment: Thanks Aless! Will support for the tomcat8 node type be added at some point in the future?

Comment: Hello Edgar. I think this case will be implemented with Dockers in the future and there will be no need to use these placeholders.